# How would I view the next image in an array of images?

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, indexing

In this function, I need to change the image of the image view, moving it onto the next image in the array.

```
private func updateImage(index: Int) {
    for x in 0..<urlArray.count
    {
        let imageUrl:URL = URL(string: "\(urlArray.object(at: x) as! String)")!
        let request:URLRequest = URLRequest.init(url: imageUrl)
        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: OperationQueue.main, completionHandler: { (response, imageDta, error) in
            if (error == nil)
            {
                self.imagesArray.add(UIImage(data: imageDta!)!)
                if self.imagesArray.count > 0
                {
                    self.iv.image = self.imagesArray.object(at: 0) as! UIImage
                }
            }else{
                print("ERROR - \(error!)")
            }
        })
    }

}
```

However, currently, the image being used is set as the image at index 0 in my array. How would I move onto the next image if this function is called multiple times?

This is the line that I mainly need help with:

```
self.iv.image = self.imagesArray.object(at: 0) as! UIImage
```

UPDATE: I've tried to add the code Charly Pico suggested to my functions but it doesn't seem to be moving onto the next image in the array, I think it's to do with how it's being called. I'm going to go into detail in how my file is constructed and works to hopefully clarify how I want to use the change image code.

```
var urlArray:NSMutableArray! = NSMutableArray()
var imagesArray:NSMutableArray! = NSMutableArray()
```

These arrays which hold the URL's and Images are outside of any function.

```
func GetTheStories() {
    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Content")
    ref.observe(FIRDataEventType.value, with: {(snapshot) in
        self.fileArray.removeAll()
        if snapshot.childrenCount>0{
            for content in snapshot.children.allObjects as![FIRDataSnapshot]{
                let contentInfo = content.value as? [String: String]
                let contentType = contentInfo?["contentType"]
                let storyLink = contentInfo?["pathToImage"]
                let content = storyLink   
                self.urlArray = NSMutableArray.init(array:[storyLink])                    
            }   
        }  
    })
}
```

This is the function I call to append the URL's from my Firebase server to the URLSARRAY.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    for x in 0..<urlArray.count
    {
        let imageUrl:URL = URL(string: "\(urlArray.object(at: x) as! String)")!
        let request:URLRequest = URLRequest.init(url: imageUrl)
        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: OperationQueue.main, completionHandler: { (response, imageDta, error) in
            if (error == nil)
            {
                self.imagesArray.add(UIImage(data: imageDta!)!)
                if self.imagesArray.count > 0
                {
                    self.iv.image = self.imagesArray.object(at: 0) as! UIImage
                }
            }else{
                print("ERROR - \(error!)")
            }
        })
    }
}
```

This is the function Charly created and explained which allows me to set the initial image on the ImageView when the screen loads

```
private func updateImage(index: Int) {
    var imageToPresent = 0
    for x in 0..<urlArray.count
    {
        let imageUrl:URL = URL(string: "\(urlArray.object(at: x) as! String)")!
        let request:URLRequest = URLRequest.init(url: imageUrl)
        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: OperationQueue.main, completionHandler: { (response, imageDta, error) in
            if (error == nil)
            {
                self.imagesArray.removeAllObjects()
                self.imagesArray.add(UIImage(data: imageDta!)!)
                if self.imagesArray.count > 0
                {
                    for x in 0..<self.imagesArray.count
                    { 
                        if self.iv.image == self.imagesArray.object(at: x) as! UIImage
                        {
                            imageToPresent = x + 1 
                            if imageToPresent >= self.imagesArray.count
                            {   
                                imageToPresent = 0
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    self.iv.image = self.imagesArray.object(at: imageToPresent) as! UIImage
                }
            }else{
                print("ERROR - \(error!)")
            }
        })
    } 
}
```

This is the function being called to update the image to the next one in the array. However, I believe it's not working either because my attempt to apply Charly's code below is not correct. This function is called in the ViewDidLoad like so

```
updateImage(index: 0)
```

And it is called to update the image here. This function is called when the Segmented progress bar changes to the next one.

```
func segmentedProgressBarChangedIndex(index: Int) {
    print("Now showing index: \(index)")
    updateImage(index: index)
}
```

I know it's a bit confusing as to why I'm not using buttons and actions, this is mainly because I'm trying to create an Instagram-style story, with segments that when finished, or the screen is tapped, change the image to the next in the array. I know there's a lot to look over but I think this will explain how I want to use the images array in greater detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so, lets say that your `imagesArray` contains 2 images, what I recommend doing is the following:

```
//Create a @IBAction and attach it to a UIButton in your Storyboard as a touchUpInside action.
@IBAction func changeImage()
{
   //Set a variable with Int as 0.
   var imageToPresent = 0

   //Create a for to check image by image inside the array.
   for x in 0..<imagesArray.count
   {

      //Compare the image at self.iv with the image in imagesArray at index x. And if the images are the same add a + 1 to imageToPresent.
      if self.iv.image == imagesArray.object(at: x) as! UIImage
      {
         imageToPresent = x + 1

         //Check if imageToPresent isn't bigger or equal than imagesArray, otherwise we will get an error and the App will crash.
         if imageToPresent >= imagesArray.count
         {

            //If imageToPreset if bigger or equal to imagesArray.count, it means that there are no more images at a higher index, so we return imageToPresent to 0.
            imageToPresent = 0
         }
      }
   }

   //Set the new image of imagesArray at index imageToPresent as UIImage to self.iv.
   self.iv.image = imagesArray.object(at: imageToPresent) as! UIImage
}
```

Every time you want to change `self.iv image` you need to touch the button for the action to be triggered.

UPDATE

So I added a NSTimer to simulate that in 3 seconds your `Progress View` finishes animating, after the 3 seconds it rotates the image to another one, you can add this code after the `for` that loads all the images from the urls:

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 3.0, repeats: true) { (timer) in
        self.changeImage()
    }
```

And first of all update your urlArray to this:

```
urlArray = NSMutableArray.init(array: ["https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/motive-73352.appspot.com/o/Content%2F20170525130622.jpg?alt=media&token=1e654c60-2f47-43c3-9298-b0282d27f66c","https://www.videomaker.com/sites/videomaker.com/files/styles/magazine_article_primary/public/articles/18984/363%20C03%20Lighting%20primary.png"])
```

So you have at least 2 images to make the image rotation.

Comment: I'll give this a shot tomorrow, thank you for the help!

Comment: I've tried adding this code to the updateImage Function but it doesn't quite seem to be working. I'm going to post an Update with a more detailed showing of how the code is working

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry for not answering for a while, been busy. Why are you using a Segmented Progress Bar?

Comment: No problem, I'm trying to create my own version of an Instagram story using content pulled from my database. It's mainly for a prototype in order to demonstrate the functionality I want to achieve eventually

Comment: Oh I understand, so when the Progress Bar completes you change of image right?

Comment: Yeah, that's what's supposed to happen but it doesn't change to the next image right now and I'm not really sure why

Comment: No worries, let me create an example for you and I will update my answer.

Comment: I've tried adding your code and I think I may have figured out what the problem is. When I print my UrlsArray straight after I've appended my links to it (In the function where I make my Firebase Request), It comes up with all the links, however, when I try to print it when I'm using it to download the images, it changes to one url that's been repeated twice so it's the same image. Not really sure why the append of my url's hasn't saved to the array so I can access them in the downloadImages function. Any suggestions?

Comment: Ok, I think I know what's happening now. When I have the viewDidAppear function running, it somehow overrides the urlArray and sets it to be the first url twice. However, when I remove this function, it doesn't seem to be downloading the images anymore and it crashes saying `index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'` for the images array.

Comment: Yeah after adding your manual array, the images changed exactly how they should so it's definitely a problem with appending to and reading the urlArray. Btw, thank you again for all your help, I wouldn't be anywhere near this without all your help :)

Comment: Ok, hopefully, final update. I've moved the function where I download the urls and append them into the array into the same function where I download the images. This has solved the issues I've left in the last few comments. However, now I have a problem with going through the images with the progress bar. Each time the progress bar moves to the next one, the UIImage flicks through every image in the array instead of just moving to the next one. Any suggestions? I can post my updated code if that helps?

Comment: if you moved the function I created for you, inside the function where the images are downloaded, you're then downloading all the images again when the Progress Bar finishes and of course you will just get a flick and set the same image that was before to the `UIImageView`. So go back to the old code, do not merge the functions.

Comment: Ok, I've changed a few things around. I've removed the changeImage function back out like you suggested and am calling that when the progress bar changes to the next one. This works! Final few problems though, for some reason the first image and timer when the screen loads does not appear despite the `updateImage(index: 0)` being called in the `viewDidLoad`. Also, I need to figure out the `imageArray.count` but when I try to do this in the `viewDidLoad`, I only ever get back 0, even after I've called the `updateImage` function

Comment: Figured it out! Added a time delay on everything to allow time for the images to download into the array. It's a messy solution but it does the job for what I need. Thank you again sooooo much Charly for all your help over the last week. I can't express my gratitude fully over comments.

Comment: No worries my friend, anything you need here I am, but before asking something, give it a shot to try everything you already know, that was the way I learned all the things I know today. ;)

Answer (score 0):

change the line to use the index being passed into your function like this

```
self.iv.image = self.imagesArray.object(at: index) as! UIImage
```

Answer (score 0):

This function is trying to do a lot of things at once, so it's hard to tell how to make it do what you want, but, you do have an index parameter.  Using that instead of the 0 here:

```
  if self.imagesArray.count > index
  {
        self.iv.image = self.imagesArray.object(at: index) as! UIImage
  }
```

Would wait for that image to load and then set that to the view.

NOTE: you need to check that the index is within bounds